# Prove 5/3 is the common ratio.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given the following sequence and asked to prove that 5/3 is the common ratio.  $a_n = \frac{5^{n-1}}{3^n},n>=1$

The book answer gives the following proof.  I can follow it all the way to the last step.  Here it is:

$\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n} = \frac{\frac{5^{(n+1)-1}}{3^{n+1}}}{\frac{5^{n-1}}{3^n}}=\frac{5^n}{3^{n+1}}*\frac{3^n}{5^{n-1}} = \frac{5}{3}$

I know this is some basic rule of exponents that I'm missing but how did he get that $\frac{5^n}{3^{n+1}}*\frac{3^n}{5^{n-1}}$ is equal to $\frac{5}{3}$??

Comment: Your question is unreadable, please format it so we can read it. I don't know what's supposed to be in the exponent and what not. To write more than one symbol in exponent, use `5^{(n+1)}` (resulting in $5^{(n+1)}$) or even better, `5^{n+1}` (resulting in $5^{n+1}$) instead of `5^(n+1)` (resulting in $5^(n+1)$).

Comment: I put all of the exponents in parentheses but for some reason mathjax isn't formatting them as one exponent.  I've been searching the web but not sure how to group them so they are seen as the exponent.

Comment: see my expanded answer, and also any mathjax tutorial, for explanation.

Comment: Try putting exponents and subscripts in braces { }.

Comment: @paw88789.  That helped!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{5^n}{3^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{5^{n-1}} = \frac{5^n}{5^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{5^{n-1}\cdot 5}{5^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{3^n\cdot 3} = \frac{5^{n-1}}{5^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{3^n}\cdot\frac{5}{3}=1=1\cdot1\cdot\frac{5}{3}=\frac53$$

Comment: can you explain some of these steps?  I don't know how you got from step one to step two.  It looks like you just swapped the denominators.

Comment: @maybedave That's exactly what I did. $$\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a\cdot c}{b\cdot d} = \frac{a\cdot c}{d\cdot b}=\frac{a}{d}\cdot\frac{c}{b}$$ proves that you can indeed swap denominators.

Comment: now that is pretty cool!  Let me look at the other steps.

Comment: @maybedave No offense, but a person already doing algebra calculus should know this by now. It's basic algebra you learn when you are, I dunno, 14 years old, while matrices are usually high-school or even university level stuff.

Comment: yeah well, I'm a 47 year old professional who works 12 hours a day and is learning this via a txt book in my spare time.  Sorry if I'm not as smart as you.

Comment: @maybedave Like I said, I didn't mean to offend, I am just worried that you are going at this the wrong way. Like you are learning to sprint, but want to do it without learning to walk before that. Mathematics, just like any solid structure, is built from strong foundations that one should have a thorough grasp of before building the second floor. I did not write what I wrote to offend, but to warn you that you should work on those basics if you don't want to get bogged down by them all the time.

Comment: its all good.  Thanks for the help!